# Saving data in multiple database sets

Tags: database, asp.net-mvc-3, save, dbset

I have a database context with multiple database set. I have an edit (httpget) and an edit (httppost) method. I want to save specific data in specific datasets. How can I specify which database set I want to use? BTW, the view from of the Edit method uses several models.

My database context looks like this:

```
public class mycontext :DBContext
{
  public DBSet<Table1> table1{get; set;}
  public DBSet<Table2> table2{get; set;}
  public DBSet<Table3> table3{get; set;}
}
```

When I define

```
private mycontext data = new mycontext()
```

The only option is `data.SaveChanges()`. I want to so something like
`data.table1.SaveChanges()` and pass in the data I want to save.

Comment: The whole point of the `DbContext` in Entity Framework is that it keep track of the changes itself, and saves out whatever is needed, all in one transaction, when you call `.SaveChanges()` on it. You cannot just save half the changes, on one table - all the changes you've made to the context will be saved - all at once

Comment: Thanks. But say I have a field whose value depend on the button clicked to submit the form and I need to update that field in the table. How will I do that please?

Answer (score 1):

if you only want to update data in **Table1**, modify only data in **Table1**, and then call `.SaveChanges()`